# LayoutManager doesn't work well with a background-image content pane

Tags: java

i'm having a little trouble positioning my components on the container which draws an image as background. why is this so? i want those four buttons aligned vertically somewhere at the right side of the frame. whatever layouting technique i use, the buttons' positions just appear to be unchanged.

[image: "JFrame"]

here's my background image panel. is there anything in it responsible for this unchangeability of the components? does it lack something?

```
    static class bgImagePanel extends JPanel {
     Image bgimage = null;

      bgImagePanel(BorderLayout b) {
      MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
      bgimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bgimage1.jpg");
      mt.addImage(bgimage, 0);
        try {
         mt.waitForAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }

      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int imwidth = bgimage.getWidth(null);
      int imheight = bgimage.getHeight(null);
      g.drawImage(bgimage, 1, 1, imwidth, imheight, null);
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can always edit your own posts.

Comment: In which part of your code do you set the layout manager? You pass-in a `BorderLayout` in its constructor but you never call `setLayout(b)` or `super(b)` to override its default layout manager (`FlowLayout`)

Comment: Where is the borderlayout "b" ? where do you add your buttons?

Comment: By the way, it’s a waste of resources to use the `MediaTracker` here. The only thing you get is a slowdown in the application startup as you are waiting for the image loading to complete. You can remove the entire `MediaTracker` stuff and provide `this` to the `drawImage` invocation instead of `null`. Then your `Component` acts as a “MediaTracker” as it will automatically repaint itself when the image has been loaded. So the application can start faster (or even use multiple cores more efficiently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be you never override the default layout manager (`FlowLayout`) in your `bgImagePanel`. You should call `super(b)` or `setLayout(b)` in its constructor:

```
public bgImagePanel(BorderLayout b) {
    super(b);
    MediaTracker mt = new MediaTracker(this);
    bgimage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("bgimage1.jpg");
    mt.addImage(bgimage, 0);
    try {
       mt.waitForAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}
```